# Cannot import python-numpy using Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Currently I am trying to import numpy using the python command but I am getting the error which is:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named numpy`

I have already installed the latest version of numpy and my python version is 2.7.10.

Comment: How did you install `numpy` using `apt-get` or `pip`..

Comment: I used apt-get to install numpy

Comment: Make sure you installed it for `python2` not `python3`

Comment: Check if you can import it in python3

Comment: Try  find / -iname '*numpy*'

Answer (score 0):

try pip freeze to find whether the module numpy is installed, If its not then try pip install numpy, also check weather in the environmental variable that the /Scripts is added because that's where all the packages reside.

Comment: then it is definetly a problem in the environmental variable, try changing it which it should say Python27/Scripts

Comment: did it work? changing the environmental Variable in ubuntu?